# In vb.net what's the deal with these variable being surrounded by sharp parenthesis?

Tags: vb.net

I was reviewing some of my colleagues vb.net code the other day and was mystified at a new level - Unfortunately I don't have the code at hand but it looked something like this:

```
Public Class foo
  Public Function [new]([bar] As String, [baz] As String) As String
    Return String.Concat([bar], baz)
  End Function
End Class
```

I have never seen these sharp parenthesis surrounding the name of the function and variable. Anyone can explain to me what the purpose of this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because "new" is a keyword and using [ ] is telling the compiler that it should read the keyword as a literal string instead. This way you can use keywords as variable and method names ... if you wanted.

I think the usage around the variables [bar] and [baz] is just .... well, because he could.

Comment: I have also seen this when I have converted c# code to vb. The converter inserted square brackets...